# How can I add dynamicaly new attribute for a class in PHP thanks new DB column names?

Tags: php, class, dynamic, attributes

I have an existing Class named `People`. 
For some reasons, in my program you can add column in the table `people` of my SQL database.
I would like to add dynamically a new attribute for each new DB column.

*DB Table People*

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | first_name | last_name | email <- new column |
------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |   John     |   Doe     |  john.doe@test.com  |
```

*PHP People Class*

```
namespace MyPlugin\Common;

class People{

    public $people_id;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;

    public function __construct( $data ){
        $this->people_id = $data["people_id"];
        $this->first_name = $data["first_name"];
        $this->last_name = $data["last_name"];
        //<-- add new attribute $this->email
    }

}
```

Is there a solution for that case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that but it is a bit dangerous,

that would look like

```
class People{

  public function __construct( $data ){
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
  }
}
```

but yes, it would be cleaner with the magic methods, it would look like

```
class People{

    public $data = array();

    public function __construct( $data ){
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        if (isset($this->data[$name])) $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if (isset($this->data[$name])) return $this->data[$name];
        else return false;
    }
}
```